# Numpy LinAlg quandary: is there a trick to using np.linalg.inv?

Tags: python, numpy

In the code pasted below, I have two arrays (matrices) - a,b - where 'b' is the inverse of 'a'. A dot product therefore should, an initially does give us 'I', the identify matrix. All good until I use np.linalg.inv to get 'b1`, which btw looks like 'b', but the dot product gives a way diff answer in 'I1'.

What gives? And yes, this is a non-zero det and all that. It's a simple example but I'm missing something like how to address floating points or something else.

```
import numpy as np

    a = np.array([[0,1,2], [1,2,3], [3,1,1]])
    b = np.array([[1/2,-1/2,1/2], [-4,3,-1],[5/2,-3/2,1/2]])
    
    I = np.dot(a,b)
    I
    ###
    array([[1., 0., 0.],
           [0., 1., 0.],
           [0., 0., 1.]])
    ###
    
    #vs
    b1 = np.linalg.inv(a)
    I1 = np.dot(a,b1)
    I1
    ### 
    array([[1.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.11022302e-16],
           [8.88178420e-16, 1.00000000e+00, 2.22044605e-16],
           [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00]])
    ###
```

Comment: `assert np.allclose(I, I1)`, both results are equal within their calculation accuracy.

Comment: The off-diagonal terms in `I1` are all tiny. They are normal floating point errors that result from the finite precision of the computer's floating point representation.  Another simple example: with `a = np.array([[3, 4], [1, 3]]); b = np.array([[3/5, -4/5], [-1/5, 3/5]])`, both `a @ b` and `b @ a` will have tiny values in the off-diagonal positions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and yes, I know about the assert "solution", but this seems troubling given, if you look at 'b1' you get:
```
[[ 0.5 -0.5  0.5]
 [-4.   3.  -1. ]
 [ 2.5 -1.5  0.5]]
```
...which looks like 'b'. So, if the assert is needed because of the dot-product function, couldn't that be updated with some default accuracy level as a default/configurable param? This "solution", correct as it is, just seems like a hack. 
But if this assert is the answer, that's what I'll live with for now and thanks. And if these other questions stir up some thoughts, great!